# Won't go back to Stage 0, goes to the next stage instead

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

In this code, the main issue is that if "Full.PNG" is detected, it is supposed to do a few actions and then reset back to Stage 0. However, instead, it does the actions but then goes onto the next Stage. An example of what I mean is that on Stage 3, it detects "Full.PNG" and activates CheckForFull(), causing Stage 3 to become Stage 0 due to Stage equaling = 0.

```
import pyautogui, pydirectinput, random, time, keyboard, ait

def CheckForFull():
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("Full.PNG", confidence = .8, grayscale = True):
            pydirectinput.moveTo(940, 689)
            ait.click()
            pydirectinput.moveTo(500, 500)
            pydirectinput.press("esc")
            pydirectinput.press("r")
            pydirectinput.press("enter")
            Stage = 0
            pass
    else:
        pass
def CheckForShop():
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("Exit.PNG", confidence = .8, grayscale = True):
        pydirectinput.moveTo(957, 1000)
        ait.click()
        pydirectinput.moveTo(500, 500)
        pydirectinput.press("esc")
        pydirectinput.press("r")
        pydirectinput.press("enter")
        Stage = 0
        pass
def CheckForRebirths():
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("TopRebirths.PNG", confidence = .4):
        pydirectinput.press("esc")
        pydirectinput.press("r")
        pydirectinput.press("enter")
        Stage = 0
def CheckForAll():
    CheckForFull()
    CheckForShop()
    CheckForRebirths()
Stage = 0 # Starting stage, stage for reset.
keyDown = pydirectinput.keyDown
keyUp = pydirectinput.keyUp
time.sleep(1.5)

while True:
    CheckForAll()
    if Stage == 0:
        for i in range(2):
            pydirectinput.press(["space","w", "a", "s", "d", "r"]) # Do it two times, make sure it works.
        keyDown("w")
        keyDown("space")
        time.sleep(8)
        keyUp("space")
        keyUp("w") # Now in the fields...
        Stage = 1 # If the checks go well, go to Stage 1.
        CheckForAll()
    elif Stage == 1:
        keyDown("d")
        time.sleep(3)
        keyUp("d")
        Stage = 2 
        CheckForAll()
    elif Stage == 2:
        keyDown("w")
        time.sleep(3)
        keyUp("w")
        Stage = 3
        CheckForAll()
    elif Stage == 3:
        keyDown("a")
        time.sleep(3)
        keyUp("a")
        Stage = 4
        CheckForAll()
    elif Stage == 4:
        keyDown("s")
        time.sleep(3)
        keyUp("s")
        Stage = 1
        CheckForAll()
    else:
        print("Stage system is broken...")
```

I have tried rearranging the Stage lines and removing "pass" from a few parts. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

assign the variable Stage on top of the script:

```
import pyautogui, pydirectinput, random, time, keyboard, ait

Stage = 0 # Starting stage, stage for reset.

def CheckForFull():
```

If this does not work, please reply to this answer and send me your error code

Comment: There was no error code, however it did not work. It still continued to the next Stage instead of going back to Stage 0 after it finished the CheckForFull().